# output formatting with git diff-tree / log

Tags: git

I'm a newbee to git. I'm trying to generate a diff between 2 branches or tags to get a list of files that have changed between the 2 and store this list of files [1 per line] (along with some other details) in a file say "changelist.txt"

Basically this is kind of format I want my output file to have:

[AbbrvHash1] [AbbrvHash2] [FullHash1] [FullHash2] [TypeOfChange] [FileName] [CommitComment(only the first 14 characters of the comment of AbbrvHash1)] [Date/time of the Hash1 commit] [Commiter ID]

9 pieces of info per line and sorted per AbbrvHash1

I've tried using git "diff-tree" and "log". Individually, they give partial info. I'm trying to see how to merge the 2 outputs from diff-tree and log into 1 flie, to give me the above output.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems like you need a script to pull everything together. Are you missing how to get any specific part of the output you want?

Comment: Yes I do believe I'll need a script for this and since I'm not that great at scriping as yet, some help would be appritiated. Also, the bigger issue is which commands in GIT will actually give me all that info I'm looking for from either git diff-tree or git log or possibly both?

Answer (score 0):

All the information you need can be extracted using `git show` and the `--pretty=format:<string>` option.

For example to display solely the hash of any given treeish, in this case `HEAD`:

```
git show -s HEAD --pretty="%H"
```

Notice that `-s` supresses the diff output that `show` usually prints, and that `--pretty="<string>"` is a shorthand for the `--pretty=format:<string>` option.

For the data you need you could base your script in the following commands:

```
git show --name-status <treeish> --pretty="%H %h %P %p %ce %at"
```

The above will print:

- full hash
- short hash
- full parent hashes
- short parent hashes
- user email
- unix timestamp of commit
- two newlines
- A list of files that were modified in this commit, with a format similar to `git status --short`

The only missing part is the commit message, which can be printed on its own with:

```
git show -s <treeish> --pretty="%B"
```

There is also an alternate form that sanitizes the subject line, so that it could be used as a file name:

```
git show -s <treeish> --pretty="%f"
```

All the different options can be found [in the `git show` documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html), look for the "PRETTY FORMATS" section.